# How can I put back the Messages window back to the main Notebook?

Tags: warning-messages, windows, message-coding

After I have clicked something, the errors started popping up in the separate Messages window. I want them to show up in the main window, with the output. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences -> Messages and choose the desired option for Kernel Messages.